# CME Publishing Issue - "The number of render failures has exceeded its specified failure limit of 0."

Tags: publishing, cme, publishingfailed

When publishing a Page it is failing straight away. This isn't happening on all pages but just a few. Looking into the Publish Transaction in the publishing process details it says:

**"The number of render failures has exceeded its specified failure limit of 0."**

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is rendering issue, where some of the resolved items cannot be rendered correctly. Please make note, that when you are publishing item, in most cases you are no publishing JUST THAT ITEM.

You are publishing all related items within that transaction also. If any of them fails, your entire transaction will fail, and you will receive this message. To see which one failed, as Atila said, please check "Processed Items" tab of Transaction itself for more details. [image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Looking into this it then says "Unable to cast object of type 'Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Schema' to type 'Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.IWorkflowItem'."?

Comment: Yes, this iss clasic InvalidCastException. You should debug your code and see what is causing this issue :) I will give you a hint. If you have workflow enabled, I would start from there :)

Comment: Let me give another hint: not all item types can participate in a workflow process (i.e. implement `IWorkflowItem`).  In particular: Schemas can’t and that is what the exception is about.

Comment: Hahahahh why @Rick? I wanted to make him sweat :) What is Tridion if you dont loose your cool at least once a day. :)

Comment: Forgive me. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the Publish dialog, go to the advanced tab, and set "Ignore Failures While Generating Publishable Content". That way the publish will succeed (Warning state), and you will see the failed items when looking at the Publish Transaction. This can be an indication as to what is wrong. Most probably an error while rendering some of the Component Presentations.

Comment: I think you can also see the error in a similar way if you don’t check “Ignore Failures...” ?